# When does wireguard consume its configuration?

Tags: kubernetes, wireguard

Under which circumstances are the files under /etc/wireguard/ consumed by wireguard? I want to harden my wireguard setup on kubernetes. An init container with NET_ADMIN capability and mounted wireguard configuration is used to configure the wireguard network interface (wg0) using wg-quick. Once it completed, another container (main) without access to the wireguard configuration and without NET_ADMIN capability is started to serve peers. It works, but I would like to understand why and when it would fail, and in particular in what cases the configuration incl. private key is required.

References and setup

- [k8s init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)
- Running on Azure Kubernetes Service with kubenet and calico
- Used image:

  ```
  FROM alpine
  RUN apk update && apk add wireguard-tools
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

> Under which circumstances are the files under /etc/wireguard/ consumed by wireguard?

When you (manually) or a script or cron or systemd unit (etc) run `wg setconf|addconf|syncconf` or `wg-quick` passing an interface name or config file path.

> ...in particular in what cases the configuration incl. private key is required.

The configuration including private key is required when you want to configure and bring up the wg interface.  Generally at boot or the first time you configure a wg interface.  Once the interface is up you can delete the config files from disk...but if you reboot you will need the config again to bring the interface back up.

## Detail

There are 2 config formats.  `wg-quick` config is a superset of `wg`.

`wg-quick` is just a bash script that filters out its own config to generate a `wg` compliant config file and at the same time takes care of all the `ip addr`, `ip route`, `iptables`, etc commands needed to bring up the wireguard interface more easily.

### wg-quick

According to the [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/wireguard-tools/wg-quick.8.en.html) for wg-quick:

> `wg-quick [ up | down | save | strip ] [ CONFIG_FILE | INTERFACE ]`
>
> `CONFIG_FILE` is a configuration file, whose filename is the interface name followed by `.conf`. Otherwise, `INTERFACE` is an interface name, with configuration found at `/etc/wireguard/INTERFACE.conf`, searched first, followed by distro-specific search paths.

So for `wg-quick`...

The config file is loaded when you run `wg-quick`.

If you provide a config file path, it will take that for the interface name (e.g. `/opt/wireguard20.conf` passed to `wg-quick` will create interface with name `wireguard20`.

If you provide an interface name (e.g. `wg99`) rather than a file path, wg-quick will look for `/etc/wireguard/wg99.conf` (maybe also on some other directories).

### wg

According to the [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/wireguard-tools/wg.8.en.html) for `wg`:

Configuration filename is only specified for:

- `wg setconf`
- `wg addconf`
- `wg syncconf`

If you don't run one of those commands, config for an interface is not updated.  You can read out current config using `wg show` or `wg showconf`.

The `wg-quick` helper script [uses](https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-tools/blob/13f4ac4cb74b5a833fa7f825ba785b1e5774e84f/src/wg-quick/linux.bash#L251) `wg setconf` once it has stripped out `wg-quick`-specific config.

### Private Key concerns

You don't need to put a private key into the config file at all.  You can call `wg set ...` for almost all config.  e.g. `wg set private-key <file-path>`

From the [wg manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/wg.8.html):

> Both `private-key` and `preshared-key` must be files, because command line arguments are not considered private on most systems but if you are using bash(1), you may safely pass in a string by specifying as `private-key` or `preshared-key` the expression: `<(echo PRIVATEKEYSTRING)`.

So once you have configured the interface you don't need the private key until you reboot again because the interface needs to be brought up and configured at reboot.

If you have enabled `wg-quick@wg0.service` to persist interface across reboots, all that does is call `wg-quick wg0` for you which then expects to find everything it needs (including private key) in `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`.  That unit file supports start/stop (no reload) so config will only be read at start (if you do it manually or by reboot).

The systemd unit that brings up the wg interface should run as root and so the private key can of course be in a root-owned 600 perm file.

If that is not secure enough for you, be aware that anyone with root access to the system can run `wg show wg0 private-key` ...so you won't be able to hide the private key from root once configured on the interface.

Comment: The interface works after restarting container _main_ without mounted private key and configuration. In main, `wg show wg0 private-key` as root fails with "Unable to access interface: Operation not permitted" – I guess due to missing NET_ADMIN capability – so `wg-quick` is probably not run on container restarts (which might differ from reboots as in your answer). Where is the interface configuration persisted? On the node?

Comment: wireguard is part of the linux kernel, and as docker containers don't have a kernel I would expect the wireguard interface management lives in the host rather than the container.  Maybe reading through this page helps?  https://www.wireguard.com/netns/